# How do these four methods for finding the first element of a vector that matches a predicate compare?

Tags: r, indexing, match, logical-operators

I've found many such ways. To start out, I'll set up my data and my predicate function:

```
set.seed(123)
data<-sample(66,20)
print(data)
#31 51 14  3 42 50 54 43 37 52 64 60 25 26 27  5 57 28  9 29
isFour<-function(x) x==4 #Not in our data
isFourteen<-function(x) x==14 #Element 3 of our data
```

I know of four methods for finding the index at which the first element of `data` that matches our predicate function occurs. The below cases all have `data` where a unique match to `isFourteen` occurs. They all return `3`.

```
which(isFourteen(data))[1]
which.max(isFourteen(data))
match(TRUE,isFourteen(data))
Position(isFourteen,data)
```

When there is a match that is not unique, they all return the index of the first match. Among these methods, the only ones that can change their behavior in this case are `which` (because we can use `[` to select an element other than `1`) and `Position` (pass `right=TRUE` and it will find the last matching index instead of the first).

The most interesting case is when there is no match:

```
which(isFour(data))[1]
#Returns NA because we're subsetting integer(0). No argument can customize this output.
which.max(isFour(data))
#Returns 1 because the only value is FALSE. This is a dangerous answer.
match(TRUE,isFour(data))
#Returns NA, but can be customised by the nomatch argument e.g. nomatch = stop("IDIOT!")
#match() also has the incomparables argument, but I've never found a use for it.
Position(isFour,data)
#Same as match, but doesn't have an incomparables argument.
```

Is there any objective reason - e.g. performance, culture, or safety - that one of these methods can be preferred?

For the three categories above, I've noticed the following:

- Performance: `Position` is written entirely in R, every other function in discussion is mostly in C.
- Culture: The documentation for `which.max` suggests the `match(TRUE,...)` method and the documentation for `which` suggests that `match` is efficient (no surprises there, `which` finds every element and subsets that, `match` just finds the first). These recommendations for `match`, coupled with the fact that I never see `Position` mentioned outside of its own documentation, suggests that `match` is more idiomatic.
- Safety: I've already demonstrated a major danger with `which.max`. As for the others, `which` offers no way to protect yourself from the `NA`, but `Position` and `match` do.

For the sake of avoiding opinion-based answers, I strongly suggest that any answer includes some sort of benchmarking and demonstrations of the lack of safety of any functions that they claim are risky to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite your request, I guess that a lot is opinion based; nonetheless, here is my take.

It really depends on the use case. Even your question might hide ambiguity; here I see two different tasks:

1. find (the position of) the first element of a `list` that obeys a condition
2. find (the position of) the first TRUE value inside a `logical` vector.

Of course, the second task solves also the first, but with the cost of applying the predicate for each element of the list.

A lot has to do with vectorization in R: for many tasks, even if "algorithmically" wrong, it's more convenient to evaluate the predicate for each element of the list and then find the `TRUE` position. This is certainly the case of your examples: there is no doubt that, given how `isFour` and the other are defined that `match` is to prefer: we don't mind to check each element of `data` since the operation is very fast, even if one could stop before the end to get the answer. This because, if we "devectorize" your function, on average we are going to slow things a lot since subsetting and checking a single element is way slower. Consider that here I'm using list not in the R-meaning (`list` object), but just as a collection of values.

On the other hand, `Position` is thought to be used when your data is `list` and/or the `f` function is not vectorized and very expensive. Imagine for instance that `f` consists in training a machine learning model, evaluate it against some data and grabbing some performance statistics. We have a list of algorithms we want to train and we want to stop when we reach a nice performance. In this case, we don't want to train every possible model in the list (super expensive), but stop as soon as we can. So, we are going to use `Position` (see also its source code to understand why).

Regarding the two tasks that I outlined at the beginning, all your solutions deal with the second task, while only `Position` solve exactly only the first.

So, in general:

- if the predicate is vectorized and efficient, go with `match`;
- if the predicate is very expensive, go with `Position`.

Don't see much of a reason to use the other two solutions in any case: `which` and `which.max` are used mainly for other tasks and not to determine the position of a TRUE value (even if they can, of course).

Just to outline better the differences between the `match` solution and the `Position` one, here is a recap.

- For `match` the `isFour` function is applied to *each element* of the input and only *after* `match` actually acts. Of course, for the specific task of the example a better way is `match(4, data)`, since `match` will stop internally as soon as a 4 is found. But the important point is that `isFour` is applied to the whole input in your implementation.
- For `Position` instead, you pass the function, not the result of its application. Then, the function is applied element by element and when the condition is met it exits, without necessarily processing the whole input.

Now it should be clear what's to prefer: it depends on the cost of "devectorize" the function against the gain of not processing the whole input.

Comment: Your logic seems sound, but I think your two general points would be greatly strengthened by some benchmarking. Also, given that `match` is coded in C, how do you know that it isn't optimised in the same way that `Position` is?

Comment: @J.Mini  It's not a matter of being optimized (`Position` is not btw), but they do different things and what's to prefer depends on the use case. Benchmarks are not that useful if you fully understand this point.

Comment: I made an edit to highlight the differences.